# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email" after user deleted trying to re- sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I deleted a user in rails console, but I cannot add them back because the database still thinks that they exist.  How can I find the index on this deleted user so that I can delete this index?

I HAVE deleted the user with this email in rails console.  When I do User.find_by("email@email.com") or User.where(email: "email@email.com").first, it turns up 'nil'....but yet I can't add another user with this email.

I don't want to delete the ENTIRE column, just that one record.

The user no longer shows up in User.all or User.find_by("email@email.com"), but if I try to add another user with email: "email@email.com" then I get this error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

Comment: are you using redis or some type of caching?  What happens if you change find_by to find_or_create_by?  What is the result of User.where(email: "email@email.com").first?

Comment: Yes, I am using redis!  The result of User.where(email: "email@email.com").first? is nil.  When I do find_or_create_by it creates a record with that email...but the validation fails on save.

Comment: I am thinking this is an issue with the indexing the user off of the email.  I am not 100% but I know I ran into a similar issue previously with indexing a user on guid.  For some reason the custom indexes with postgres are not always updated when validations run.  This may not be related at all but check out this blog post under threats and inconveniences.  http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/